# Closed Hilbert half-space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, homotopy-theory, manifolds-with-boundary

Suppose $H$ is the seperable infinite-dimensional real Hilbert space and $f$ is a continuous linear functional on it. Is the closed half-space $H_{f \ge 0} = \{ x \in H | f(x) \ge 0 \}$ homeomorphic to $H$? They are both contractible even after taking the complement of any compact subset, so the ususal proof for finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}^n \ncong \mathbb{R}^n_{\ge 0}$ does not extend. Moreover, the famous theorem that 'Hilbert manifolds of the same homotopy type are homeomorphic' is not valid either, since $H_{f \ge 0}$ being a Hilbert manifold is precisely equivalent to $H \cong H_{f \ge 0}$. Any reference is welcome.

Comment: $[0,\infty)$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ because it remains connected when $0$ is removed from it.

Comment: @geetha290krm I think I mean infinite-dimensional. I'll change my statement.

Comment: YES, they are homeomorphic.  Answe here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/121698/454  sets 1 and 4.  A result of Bessaga & Pelczynski.